# "Generalised Isotropy"

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, permutations, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G\subseteq S_N$ be a finite permutation group and $\mathcal{P}=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^nX_i$ a partition of $\{1,\dots,N\}$.

We can define a subgroup $G_{\mathcal{P}}\subseteq G$ by:
$$G_{\mathcal{P}}:=\{\sigma\in G\,\colon\,\sigma(X_i)=X_i\}.$$

In particular, the isotropy subgroup $G_i$ is given by $G_{\mathcal{P}_i}$ where $\mathcal{P}_i:=\{i\}\sqcup(\{1,\dots,N\}\backslash \{i\})$.

> *Question: has such a construction $G_{\mathcal{P}}\subseteq G$ got a name in the literature? If not known, can be come up with a better name than "generalised isotropy". Perhaps something with "orbits"*

I see the same construction [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4225185/maximal-subgroups-of-s-n-with-a-certain-proprety).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the stabilizer subgroup of $P$, with respect to the action of $G$ on (edit: ordered / labeled) partitions.

Comment: Arguably, with respect to the action of $G$ on partitions, "the stabilizer subgroup of $P$" ought to be able to swap same-size blocks, which would in many cases yield a bigger subgroup than the one OP is asking for; OP's subgroup would be the kernel of the action of this partition stabilizer on the partition itself. I would just use "ordered partition" instead.

Comment: Yes, that's fair, I had in mind ordered / labeled partitions.